# creating a table using $_POST parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, pg-query

I'm trying to create a table where the table name is a parameter. Is it possible? Like this:

```php
$result = pg_query("CREATE TABLE '$_POST[nome_arquivo_software]' (
    id serial CONSTRAINT pk_'$_POST[nome_arquivo_software]' PRIMARY KEY,
    nome  varchar (80),
    email varchar (80),
    estado varchar (80),
    acessos numeric
)");
```

Comment: This is wide open to SQL injection. You shouldn't pass user-input variables directly to the script, as you're risking your entire database.

Comment: Validate the input first before using it

Comment: @Ohgodwhy in this case I'm the only user... so I did this form just to make things faster...

Comment: what do you mean, @monace19?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy your name fits your comment perfectly haha!

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* - did you try it?

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva like Ohgodwhy said, that is open to SQL injection. So to prevent that, you should validate the input first to make sure it is safe to use.

Comment: @Fred-ii- of course I did! hahaha the problem is that it isn't working

Comment: @monace19 got it. In case of text to the name of table, why isn't it working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @monace19 it shows: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'test'" LINE 1: CREATE TABLE 'test'

where test is the $_POST[nome_arquivo_software], but if I try to create the table without using parameters and put the word test in the SQL code, it works. The problem is in $_POST[nome_arquivo_software].

Comment: You'll need to tell us why then. Check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error.php

Comment: it's the way you're using your  POST array and its quoting method, that's why you're getting that error. Use ticks `\`` instead of quotes or just remove them altogether. But I'd use a different method altogether.

Comment: @Fred I think it's double quotes for postgresql.

Comment: @VolkerK definitely a quotes issue, for sure ;-) I'm not familiar with postgresql.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and VolkerK you were right! All I did was remove double quotes and it worked. I'm always having trouble with this things, because it seens that for every each case you have to use different methods of quotings. Thanks you all!

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva you're welcome. You've been given an answer below where he escaped it with double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table name is not a string literal but an [identifier](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) -> change single-quote to double-quotes -> quoted identifier.

The name of the id field is not pk_+string literal but the whole thing is an identifier -> "pk_...."

```
// <--- intensive checks on $_POST[nome_arquivo_software] and $_POST[nome_arquivo_software] here
$result = pg_query("
    CREATE TABLE \"$_POST[nome_arquivo_software]\" (
    id serial CONSTRAINT \"pk_$_POST[nome_arquivo_software]\" PRIMARY KEY,
    nome  varchar (80),
    email varchar (80),
    estado varchar (80),
    acessos numeric
    )
");
```

Comment: problem solved! Your code worked too! But I think removing quotes of parameters is easier. Thanks for all tips. Stackoverflow always helps me :)

Comment: if you want uppercase letters or other unusual symbols in the name of the table then the quotes are required.